# Tried multiple IFS formula. None is working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have a column which has country names plus a few blanks.
So I want the formula to go by this :

1. IF the country name is "India" put it as India and if the country name is anything else then enter it as "International"
2. IF the row is blank enter it as "" (basically empty cell).
   I used the formula:
   IFS(H2= "India", "India", "International", ISBLANK(H2)="")
   That obviously doesn't work. I cannot assign each country different IF condition, which would solve the issue but will take a lot of time.
   Please help if anyone has any easier formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to:

```
= IFS(H2= "India", "India", ISBLANK(H2),"", H2<>"India","International")
```

It first checks if the County is India. If yes, India is displayed. If not, it checks if the cell is blank. If yes, then empty cell ("") is displayed. If the cell is not blank, it checks if the country is not India, then displays International.

Comment: Oh thanks! Didn't know about <> operator in Google Sheet.

Comment: @DhirajD If your issue is solved by the answer, please mark the question as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)